# Bergfex Leaflet Layer

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

I have used the first code to display a Bergfex layer in OpenLayers and this works up to high zoom layers whereas I cannot get a Leaflet layer to work above zoom 12.
Does anybody know if this is a limitation or are other elements needed?  I have tried it both as a base layer or overlay. Both sets of code are below.

OpenLayers:

```js
bergfex = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("Bergfex Topo Austria",
  "http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/${z}$folder/${z}_${x}_${y}.png", {
    sphericalMercator: true,
    buffer: 0,
    opacity: 0.5,
    isBaseLayer: false,
    visibility: false,
    attribution: "&copy; 2008, 2013 BEV,<a href='http://www.bergfex.at'>bergfex GmbH</a>",
    getURL: function(bounds) {
      var path = OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ.prototype.getURL.apply(this, arguments);
      var parts = path.split("$folder/");
      var z = parseInt(parts[0].substr(-2));
      path = path.replace("$folder", z >= 14 ?
        "/" + parts[1].substr(3, 2 + z - 14) : "");
      return path;
    }
  });
```

Leaflet:

```js
bf = L.tileLayer('http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/{z}/{z}_{x}_{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: bergfexAttribution,
  detectRetina: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks - it was set out in lines when I posted it.

Answer (score 2):

The URL template used in your Leaflet code (`'http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/{z}/{z}_{x}_{y}.png'`) has tiles available only above Austria, and from zoom levels 8 to 13 (included). There are no tiles (404 error) from zoom 0 to 7 (included), and zoom 14 and above.

To avoid unnecessary network request, you might be interested in using [`minZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-minzoom) and [`bounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-bounds) Tile Layer options:

```js
bf = L.tileLayer('http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/{z}/{z}_{x}_{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 13,
  minZoom: 8,
  bounds: [
    [45, 10], // I just used arbitrary bounds, you should adjust them.
    [50, 15]
  ],
  attribution: bergfexAttribution,
  detectRetina: true
});
```

Now to go beyond zoom level 13, your OpenLayers code changes that URL template dynamically (see the `getURL` options), so it looks like `'http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/{z}/{x2}/{z}_{x}_{y}.png'` with `x2` being the first 2 digits of `x` at zoom 14 and the first 3 at zoom 15 (maybe and so on).

You will need to do a similar "URL template dynamic adjustment" for Leaflet. Unfortunately, Leaflet does not expose a similar `getURL` option as OpenLayers. Nevertheless, you could modify the [`getTileUrl` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/stable/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L464-L471) of your `bf` Tile Layer instance so that it does that adjustment (you would have to adapt your OpenLayers code):

```js
var bf2 = L.tileLayer('http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/{z}/{x2}/{z}_{x}_{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18, // Looks like tiles are available only up to 15 included, or the URL template changes again?
  minZoom: 14,
  bounds: [
    [45, 10], // I just used arbitrary bounds, you should adjust them.
    [50, 15]
  ],
  attribution: bergfexAttribution,
  detectRetina: true
});

bf2.getTileUrl = function (tilePoint) {
  var x2 = Math.floor(tilePoint.x / 100);

  return L.Util.template(this._url, L.extend({
      s: this._getSubdomain(tilePoint),
      z: tilePoint.z,
      x: tilePoint.x,
      y: tilePoint.y,
      x2: x2
    }, this.options));
};

bf2.addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/217/

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome! If your issue is solved, please can you also mark this answer as accepted, so that people know?

Comment: I can get this to work to zoom 14 but not to 15 as in http://outdoormaps.eu/ based on OpenLayers.  Should it be working to 15?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention - you can zoom to 15.  It pauses for a few seconds and then defaults to a base map.

Comment: On Zoom level 14, it seems to be looking at level 15:

http://static7.bergfex.at/images/amap/15/174/15_17427_11488.png
Map Clicked at: Long: 11.4015E : Lat: 47.2745N : Elevation: 581m : Zoom Level: 14

Is there a simple way to get it to look at levels 13 to 15 or is this a Leaflet limitation?

Comment: I have found your tile to be at `[47.2745, 11.4615]`. The above demo correctly uses tiles set 14 at zoom 14 and tiles set 15 at zoom 15: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/219/ You may have a bug in your code, feel free to open a new question and share your code for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks.  On my iPhone, Android and laptop running Bootcamp/OSX the Fiddle demo shows 14 correctly but fails at 15.  Is this a limitation of the equipment or is there another setting?

15 appears to load and then a couple of seconds later, it displays OSM.

Comment: I see. This is because of the [`detectRetina` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-detectretina). When it detects a Retina display, it will use tiles from zoom level +1 (so when you are at zoom level 14, it will actually use tiles of zoom 15). Hence at zoom 15 it will no longer have tiles. You can use [`maxNativeZoom` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-maxnativezoom) to force Leaflet to keep using tiles of zoom 15 and expand them (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/223/).